# List changing value from boolean "true" to "3"

Tags: android, app-inventor

So i'm using AppInventor 2, when i load my screen i have passed a list in from a previous screen as the start value for the current screen

[image]

Here we can see that the list is set as (true, true, 1,0,0,0) which is what it's supposed to be but when i try to edit it in the next screen:

[image]

can anyone shed some light on what is happening here???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the **select list item** block to select an item from a list
[image]

the **index in list** block will give you the index of a specific thing in a list... the thing you are looking for is 1, so the result is 3 in your example

see also the documentation http://appinventor.mit.edu/explore/ai2/support/blocks/lists.html#selectlistitem

Comment: Thanks!! working perfect, cant believe that was the mistake!